# SQL 1-many not returning all records

Tags: mysql, sql

This should be SQL 101, but I'm missing something.

I have 2 tables. Questions and Answers (4 possible answers for each question).
Trying to write a query that returns every question with every possible answer for that question. Here's what the 2 tables look like (truncated).

```
+---+--------------+
| X | Question     |
+---+--------------+
| 1 | A lesion is  |
| 2 | A linear acc |
| 3 | A patient wi |
| 4 | A small tumo |
+---+--------------+

+---+--------------+-----+
| X | Answer       | Crt |
+---+--------------+-----+
| 1 | 12 MeV       | Yes |
| 1 | 9 MeV        | No  |
| 1 | 6 MeV        | No  |
| 1 | 16 MeV       | No  |
| 2 | 6 MeV        | Yes |
| 2 | 5 MeV        | No  |
| 2 | 12 MeV       | No  |
| 2 | 20 MeV       | No  |
| 3 | Prostate siz | Yes |
| 3 | T1-T2a       | No  |
| 3 | Gleason scor | No  |
| 3 | PSA <10      | No  |
| 4 | contains few | Yes |
| 4 | contains a h | No  |
| 4 | is easier to | No  |
| 4 | is more easi | No  |
+---+--------------+-----+
```

Here's what I'm trying to get by keying on X

```
+---+--------------+--------------+-----+
| X | Question     | Answer       | Crt |
+---+--------------+--------------+-----+
| 1 | A lesion is  | 12 MeV       | Yes |
| 1 | A lesion is  | 9 MeV        | No  |
| 1 | A lesion is  | 6 MeV        | No  |
| 1 | A lesion is  | 16 MeV       | No  |
| 2 | A linear acc | 6 MeV        | Yes |
| 2 | A linear acc | 5 MeV        | No  |
| 2 | A linear acc | 12 MeV       | No  |
| 2 | A linear acc | 20 MeV       | No  |
| 3 | A patient wi | Prostate siz | Yes |
| 3 | A patient wi | T1-T2a       | No  |
| 3 | A patient wi | Gleason scor | No  |
| 3 | A patient wi | PSA <10      | No  |
| 4 | A small tumo | contains few | Yes |
| 4 | A small tumo | contains a h | No  |
| 4 | A small tumo | is easier to | No  |
| 4 | A small tumo | is more easi | No  |
+---+--------------+--------------+-----+
```

This works fine in Access.
But in MySQL (5.6) I get

```
+---+--------------+--------------+-----+
| X | Question     | Answer       | Crt |
+---+--------------+--------------+-----+
| 1 | A lesion is  | 12 MeV       | Yes |
| 2 | A linear acc | 6 MeV        | Yes |
| 3 | A patient wi | Prostate siz | Yes |
| 4 | A small tumo | contains few | Yes |
+---+--------------+--------------+-----+
```

Here's the query I used.

```
SELECT Questions.X, Questions.Question, Answers.Answer, Answers.Correct
FROM Questions LEFT JOIN Answers ON Questions.X = Answers.X;
```

I've also tried INNER JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOIN, & RIGHT OUTER JOIN, all with the same results.

I've been working with various databases for so long, this seems like it should work. And I don't know of any differences between Access and MySQL that would account for this.

Please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This works fine in SQLite (I'm too lazy to spin up MySQL). The columns in your query do not match the columns in your data. For example, `Questions.Idx` vs `Questions.X`. Are you showing us the actual data, query and results?

Comment: Are you sure there is no `GROUP BY X` on that query?

Comment: At fist glance, nothing seems wrong. Try recreating this in SQLFiddle.  You're probably not showing us the whole picture.

Comment: Also note that you're joining on `X` but selecting a mysterious `Idx`.

Comment: `RIGHT JOIN` and `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` are the exact same thing, by the way (the `OUTER` keyword is optional, and they're both evil).

Comment: @sstan, your idea of using SQLFiddle made me see where the problem was. Missing data. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the tables and data you showed us, [your query works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d86c9). The problem is not with your query, it's something else you're not showing us.

Debugging time.

**Are you *sure* your tables contain the data you think they do?**

Simple way to check: `SELECT * FROM questions` and `SELECT * FROM answers`.

**Are you *sure* you're running the query on the correct database?**

Perhaps you're checking the tables in a SQL shell but running the query through a program?  Be sure to do both things with the same interface.

**Are you *sure* you're running the query you think you're running?**

You've already posted a broken query once. Maybe you're not running what you think you're running.

Did you type that query into a shell? Or is it being created and executed via some program? If it's the latter, test it in the shell and print out the complete query from the program. You can also check your MySQL query log.

**Are you *sure* your schema is what you think it is?**

Run `DESCRIBE questions` and `DESCRIBE answers` to double check there isn't anything funny going on with the table definitions.

Comment: Accepted? Which one was it?

Comment: OK, here's what the problem was. The data in Access didn't all get copied to MySQL (that's a different problem. So my query worked, just had incomplete data. I thought I was going crazy!.